# How to allow for webpack-dev-server to allow entry points from react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm creating an app that uses webpack-dev-server in development alongside react-router.

It seems that webpack-dev-server is built around the assumption that you will have a public entry point at one place (i.e. "/"), whereas react-router allows for an unlimited amount of entry points.

I want the benefits of the webpack-dev-server, especially the hot reloading feature that is great for productivity, but I still want to be able to load routes set in react-router.

How could one implement it such that they work together? Could you run an express server in front of webpack-dev-server in such a way to allow this?

Comment: I have an extremely hacky version of something here, but it is fragile and only allows simple routes to match: https://github.com/natew/react-base (see make-webpack-config) and (app/routes.js)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I set up a proxy to achieve this:

You have a regular express webserver that serves the index.html on any route, except if its an asset route. if it is an asset, the request gets proxied to the web-dev-server

your react hot entrypoints will still point directly at the webpack dev server, so hot reloading still works.

Let's assume you run webpack-dev-server on 8081 and your proxy at 8080. Your server.js file will look like this:

```
"use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./make-webpack-config')('dev');

var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
var url = require('url');

## --------your proxy----------------------
var app = express();
## proxy the request for static assets
app.use('/assets', proxy(url.parse('http://localhost:8081/assets')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


# -----your-webpack-dev-server------------------
var server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    contentBase: __dirname,
    hot: true,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: false,
    publicPath: "/assets/",

    stats: { colors: true }
});

## run the two servers
server.listen(8081, "localhost", function() {});
app.listen(8080);
```

now make your entrypoints in the webpack config like so:

```
 entry: [
     './src/main.js',
     'webpack/hot/dev-server',
     'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081'
 ]
```

note the direct call to 8081 for hotreload

also make sure you pass an absolute url to the `output.publicPath` option:

```
 output: {
     publicPath: "http://localhost:8081/assets/",
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: One question, sort of unrelated so I can open a new question if need be but I notice that now the console output from the webpack dev server isn't streamed.  Before, you could watch it compile and see the percents rise, now it just block outputs after compilation.

Comment: Nice done. This is exactly how it should be done. I added a note about the `output.publicPath` option, which should be an absolute url too.

Comment: Thanks, what do you have in assets? In my case the bundle.js dir is called `dist`. I'll keep it as that unless anything else is supposed to go in there? My app is in a folder called `app` - should they be in the same place?

Comment: It would be easier just to use a built-in [webpack proxy](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) instead. Thus you don't interfere in the server itself, you leave the server _pure_. Instead, you just do a little (3-5 lines) addition to webpack config. Thanks to that you modify only dev scripts for dev purposes and leave the production code (server.js) in peace (unlike in your version) and imo that's the proper way to go.

Comment: This fixes the issue: 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr', found @ https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/37

Comment: how do you make the `server.js` clean for production use?

Comment: @jalooc that is interesting to me. My understanding is that from a `package.json` script command you run `webpack-dev-server` using some `webpack.dev.config` where you specify the `devServer.proxy` option to point to your original local express server. But how do you start both webpack-dev-server **and** your express server from package.json script command?

Comment: @superjos in this case the express server is started independently of webpack. But of course you can join the two commands with something like `&&` and put it to package.json.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. In the meantime I found other answers mentioning [parallelshell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell). `&&` as it is would not work in that case.

Comment: @jalooc that sounds interesting, why don't you offer it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: This is the best approach I've seen. Thanks for sharing. 
Also, what are the last two entries in the entry array for? I left them out and everything seems to work fine

Comment: This answer is still correct though a bit dated. More straightforward ways are available now, look for `historyApiFallback`.

Answer (score 107):

You should set `historyApiFallback` of `WebpackDevServer` as true for this to work. Here's a small example (tweak to fit your purposes):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

var config = require('./webpack.config');


var port = 4000;
var ip = '0.0.0.0';
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    historyApiFallback: true,
}).listen(port, ip, function (err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Listening at ' + ip + ':' + port);
});
```

Comment: You will miss the statusbar on top of your index.html, but this works great :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. From the webpack dev server docs: _"If you are using the HTML5 history API you probably need to serve your index.html in place of 404 responses, which can be done by setting historyApiFallback: true"_ If I understand the question correctly this will solve the problem.

Comment: @smnbbrv No probs. It actually uses [connect-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback) underneath and you can pass an object with the middleware specific options if you want  instead of just `true`.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with webpack-dev-middleware?

Comment: @DonnyP webpack-dev-middleware doesn't do anything do anything with connect-history-api-fallback so you will have to connect it separately to your setup.

Comment: OR if you're using the cli, `webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback`

Comment: The comment from @Levi comment, above, worked for me!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! For those also using webpack.config.js, just add the "historyApiFallback: true" to the "devServer" object

Answer (score 27):

For anyone else that may still be looking for this answer.  I put together a simple proxy bypass which achieves this without much hassle and the config goes into the webpack.config.js

I am sure there are much more elegant ways to test for local content using regex, but this works for my needs.

```
devServer: {
  proxy: { 
    '/**': {  //catch all requests
      target: '/index.html',  //default target
      secure: false,
      bypass: function(req, res, opt){
        //your custom code to check for any exceptions
        //console.log('bypass check', {req: req, res:res, opt: opt});
        if(req.path.indexOf('/img/') !== -1 || req.path.indexOf('/public/') !== -1){
          return '/'
        }

        if (req.headers.accept.indexOf('html') !== -1) {
          return '/index.html';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! Is there a difference between this and just adding "historyApiFallback: true" to the same devServer object? (outside from the obvious of being able to further customize it). Just curious

Answer (score 15):

If you're running webpack-dev-server using CLI, you can configure it through webpack.config.js passing devServer object and using the [historyApiFallback option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback):

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
}
```

This will redirect to index.html everytime it 404 is encountered.

NOTE: If you're using publicPath, you'll need to pass it to devServer too:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "admin/dashboard"
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: "admin/dashboard"
    }
  }
}
```

You can verify that everything is setup correctly by looking at the first few lines of the output (the part with "404s will fallback to: **path**").

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For a more recent answer, the current version of webpack (4.1.1) you can just set this in your webpack.config.js like such:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './src/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']  
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true,
      historyApiFallback: true
    }
  };
```

The important part is `historyApiFallback: true`. No need to run a custom server, just use the cli:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to the answer for the case when you run an isomorphic app (i.e. rendering React component server-side.)

In this case you probably also want to automatically reload the server when you change one of your React components. You do this with the `piping` package. All you have to do is install it and add `require("piping")({hook: true})` somewhere in the beginning of you *server.js*. That's it. The server will restart after you change any component used by it.

This rises another problem though - if you run webpack server from the same process as your express server (as in the accepted answer above), the webpack server will also restart and will recompile your bundle every time. To avoid this you should run your main server and webpack server in different processes so that piping would restart only your express server and won't touch webpack.
You can do this with `concurrently` package. You can find an example of this in [react-isomorphic-starterkit](https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit/blob/master/package.json#L25). In the *package.json* he has:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "watch": "node ./node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js --kill-others 'npm run watch-client' 'npm run start'"
  },
```

which runs both servers simultaneously but in separate processes.

Comment: Does this mean some files are being watched twice? Such as the shared isomorphic/universal files?

Answer (score 1):

`historyApiFallback` can also be an object instead of a Boolean, containing the routes.

```
historyApiFallback: navData && {
  rewrites: [
      { from: /route-1-regex/, to: 'route-1-example.html' }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be not in all cases, but seems the `publicPath: '/'` option in the devServer is easiest solution to fix deep routes issue, see: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/676

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me: just simply add the webpack middlewares first and the `app.get('*'...` index.html resolver later,

so express will first check if the request matches one of the routes provided by webpack (like: `/dist/bundle.js` or `/__webpack_hmr_`) and if not, then it will move to the `index.html` with the `*` resolver.

ie:

```
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
}))
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler))
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  sendSomeHtml(res)
})
```