# Load routes directly when using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I recently started using react and webpack and while it is great in most respects, but when testing the app is rendered into an iframe which prevents me from being able to load non-root routes directly.  So if I want to test `http://localhost:8000/#/signin` I can't load that url, but instead I have to load the base url and click a link in it that points to the signin page (or at least that is the only way that I have found that works).

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203725/how-to-allow-for-webpack-dev-server-to-allow-entry-points-from-react-router?rq=1) with a pretty hacky solution.  Has anything changed since then?

Comment: `#/signin` *is* the root route. The hash and anything after it is not sent to the server. The URL you pasted is seen as `http://localhost:8000/` to your server.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but React should detect the #/signin hash and render the corresponding route that contains the signin component (as it does when not using webpack).

Comment: React doesn't offer routing. Are you using something like [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)?

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that.  Yes I am using react-router.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that this works: localhost:8000/webpack-dev-server/ ?

The following should work too:

- localhost:8000/webpack-dev-server/index.html
- localhost:8000/webpack-dev-server/index.html/#/signin

These should work without the iframe:

- localhost:8000/index.html/#/signin
- localhost:8000/#/signin

If that doesn't work, why don't you right click on the link that points to the signin page, copy link address and paste it into the browser?

Comment: You are right that the urls can be hard loaded.  Maybe it is a chrome thing, but if I manually change the url and click enter it doesn't change, but if I then cmd-r it will load the route.  However, the issue still stands since when I click on a link like `localhost:8000/#/foo` the browser url doesn't change.  This makes development difficult in making me manually set the browser url. Using webpack helps prevent a lot of full page reloads, but not all of them.  Is the issue that the links don't contain the webpack-dev-server path?  My links are created with the react-router Link component.

Comment: In regards to the second set of links you posted, they do work, but using them throws out all the benefits of webpack (no aync-reloading of files). As for copying the link and pasting it into the browser, I am not saying that nothing works, I am saying that productivity is broken when you have to hard reload all the time.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do what you want out of the box. When your app is running inside an iframe it will not update the browser url or history. What I don't understand is why you need webpack do async-reloading when you are testing your app. I would expect that async-reloading is only useful during development.

Comment: When I said _testing_ I meant manually testing during development.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution to this is to load the url containing the webpack path and the hash that you are testing ex. `http://localhost:8000/webpack-dev-server/#dashboard`.  This has to be done manually since any links in the app will not contain the `webpack-dev-server` path.

This allows for the occasional hard load of the page if required, but allows for webpack to perform most of the hot-loading when possible.