# How to tell webpack dev server to serve index.html for any route

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, react-router

React router allows react apps to handle `/arbitrary/route`. In order this to work, I need my server to send the React app on any matched route.

But [webpack dev server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) doesn't handle arbitrary end points.

There is a solution here using additional express server.
[How to allow for webpack-dev-server to allow entry points from react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203725/how-to-allow-for-webpack-dev-server-to-allow-entry-points-from-react-router)

But I don't want to fire up another express server to allow route matching. I just want to tell webpack dev server to match any url and send me my react app. please.

Comment: have you seen [React Router Mega Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow for webpack-dev-server to allow entry points from react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203725/how-to-allow-for-webpack-dev-server-to-allow-entry-points-from-react-router)

Answer (score 208):

I found the easiest solution to include a small config:

```
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html'
    }
  }
```

I found this by visiting: [PUSHSTATE WITH WEBPACK-DEV-SERVER](http://jaketrent.com/post/pushstate-webpack-dev-server/).

Comment: you can also use it as a CLI option: `--history-api-fallback`

Comment: I had to use something like this with the newer version 2. `devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },`

Comment: Indeed you have to use boththe cli option "--history-api-fallback" and on your webpack dev server configuration set the resolution to you index file like described on this answer above.

Comment: should be `index: '/index.html'` instead

Answer (score 115):

**[historyApiFallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback)** option on official documentation for [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) explains clearly how you can achieve either by using

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

which simply falls back to index.html when the route is not found

or

```
// output.publicPath: '/foo-app/'
historyApiFallback: {
  index: '/foo-app/'
}
```

Comment: Updated link: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver

Comment: But actually webpack-dev-server is in maintenance now. It's successor is https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve#add-function-parameters, which supports `historyApiFallback`

Comment: For anybody reading this in 2019, according to https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve#webpack-serve `webpack-dev-server` is the successor to `webpack-serve`, not the other way around as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945763/how-to-tell-webpack-dev-server-to-serve-index-html-for-any-route?answertab=oldest#comment86936567_39985334.

Comment: ur5us' comment is actually false. webpack-serve was the planned successor to webpack-dev-server. I'm the author of webpack-serve and former maintainer of webpack-dev-server. when I took some time off, bitter org members deprecated webpack-serve, and I have since released it under my fork.

Answer (score 46):

Adding public path to config helps webpack to understand real root (`/`) even when you are on subroutes, eg. `/article/uuid`

So modify your webpack config and add following:

```
output: {
    publicPath: "/"
}

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Without `publicPath` resources might not be loaded properly, only index.html.

Tested on Webpack `4.6`

*Larger part of config (just to have better picture):*

```
entry: "./main.js",
output: {
  publicPath: "/",
  path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  filename: "bundle-[hash].js"
},
devServer: {
  host: "domain.local",
  https: true,
  port: 123,
  hot: true,
  contentBase: "./public",
  inline: true,
  disableHostCheck: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Comment: Wow this worked for me as well! The `historyApiFallback` trick only worked for the last part of the URL for some reason. `/test` would work but `/test/test` would give 404.

Comment: In addition to `historyApiFallback: {index: '/'} ` or `historyApiFallback: true` (both worked for me), setting the `publicPath` was also essential in my case (Router 5.2).

Comment: The only answer solving whole problem. Thanks man!

Answer (score 19):

Works for me like this

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src",
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true

},
```

Working on riot app

Comment: Does this still exist? Not seeing it in 2023

Answer (score 14):

My situation was a little different, since I am using the angular CLI with webpack and the 'eject' option after running the [ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) command.  I modified the ejected npm script for 'npm start' in the package.json to pass in the --history-api-fallback flag

> "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200 **--history-api-fallback**"

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200 --history-api-fallback",
"build": "webpack",
"test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
"prepree2e": "npm start",
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet",
"startold": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
"testold": "karma start",
"buildold": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"},
```

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the majority of existing answers.

One key thing I wanted to mention is if you hit issues when **manually** reloading pages on **deeper paths** where it keeps the all but the last section of the path and tacks on the name of your `js` bundle file you probably need an extra setting (specifically the `publicPath` setting).

For example, if I have a path `/foo/bar` and my bundler file is called `bundle.js`. When I try to manually refresh the page I get a 404 saying `/foo/bundle.js` cannot be found. Interestingly if you try reloading from the path `/foo` you see no issues (this is because the fallback handles it).

Try using the below in conjunction with your existing `webpack` config to fix the issue. `output.publicPath` is the key piece!

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
},
...
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you choose to use `webpack-dev-server`, you should not use it to serve your entire React app. You should use it to serve your `bundle.js` file as well as the static dependencies. In this case, you would have to start 2 servers, one for the Node.js entry points, that are actually going to process routes and serve the HTML, and another one for the bundle and static resources.

If you really want a single server, you have to stop using the `webpack-dev-server` and start using the [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) within your app-server. It will process bundles "on the fly" (I think it supports caching and hot module replacements) and make sure your calls to `bundle.js` are always up to date.

Comment: I am using webpack-dev-server only for development hot reloading source maps etc. Otherwise I have a static website where I can host the files from anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

For me I had dots "." in my path e.g. `/orgs.csv` so I had to put this in my webpack confg.

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 5):

You can enable [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) to serve the `index.html` instead of an 404 error when no other resource has been found at this location.

```
let devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    historyApiFallback: true,
});
```

If you want to serve different files for different URIs, you can add basic rewriting rules to this option. The `index.html` will still be served for other paths.

```
let devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    historyApiFallback: {
        rewrites: [
            { from: /^\/page1/, to: '/page1.html' },
            { from: /^\/page2/, to: '/page2.html' },
            { from: /^\/page3/, to: '/page3.html' },
        ]
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is for webpack-dev-server, but for anyone who uses **webpack-serve 2.0.** with **webpack 4.16.5**; webpack-serve allows add-ons.You'll need to create `serve.config.js`:

```
const serve = require('webpack-serve');
const argv = {};
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');

const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const convert = require('koa-connect');

serve(argv, { config }).then((result) => {
  server.on('listening', ({ server, options }) => {
      options.add: (app, middleware, options) => {

          // HistoryApiFallback
          const historyOptions = {
              // ... configure options
          };

          app.use(convert(history(historyOptions)));
      }
  });
});
```

[Reference](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#options)

You will need to change the dev script from `webpack-serve` to `node serve.config.js`.

Answer (score 1):

To those who are still struggling to get this working with webpack > 5 like me here is the working configuration

```js
//webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'output'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,        
        historyApiFallback:true,
        static: './'
    }
}
```

index.html file is at the root level.