# Webpack and multiple Angular apps base URL issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

I am using Webpack and building multiple angular apps. I am having some issue with routing. This issue only comes when i have ***$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);*** in  my angular code.

Let say my base URL is
***abc.com***

App 1:
***abc.com/app1***

App 2:
***abc.com/app2***

Now lets say I am on one of these and go to a sub route of any of these app.

***abc.com/app1/sub-route1*** or ***abc.com/app2/sub-route2***

This scenario works fine. 
The issue comes when I do refresh or reload from browser. 
In that case it redirects to ***abc.com*** rather than staying on

***abc.com/app1/sub-route1*** or ***abc.com/app2/sub-route2***

This does not happen if I use ***$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)***;

Comment: Take a look on that question it might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16570533/5452965

Comment: @sand : thanks for the link. currently I am using Webpack dev-server and running it on localhost. any clues as to what can i do to fix this in webpack ?

Comment: Take a look on that link http://stackoverflow.com/a/34125010/5452965 or search in the web how to redirect all the traffic to `index.html`

Comment: @sand: thats the problem. I don't want all traffic to be redirected to one index.html. If it belongs to 2nd app then it to load the abc.com/app2/sub-route2 or otherwise if its first app then to abc.com/app1/sub-route1.
I'll try to look into webpack to see if there is a way to configure this.