# bundle.js not found with webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having an issue with React/Redux/Webpack/Router.

Any "sub pages", such as: "/home/test", "users/registration" etc... fail to be loaded - and I get errors loading the "bundle.js" file generated by webpack.

The reason seems to be that the request to fetch the "bundle.js" is with the following url:

for path "/home/test": "/home/bundle.js"
for path "/users/registration": "/users/bundle.js"

Same issue occurs with the loading of "css" files and other resources.

This is my webpack configuration:

```
    const { resolve } = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const OpenBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './main.js',
    //'./assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      /* {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader"
      }, */
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loaders: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              query: {
                sourceMap: false,
              },
            },
          ],
          publicPath: '../'
        }),
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=15000&name=images/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'file-loader?&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=images/[name].[ext]' },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      test: /\.js$/,
      options: {
        eslint: {
          configFile: resolve(__dirname, '.eslintrc'),
          cache: false,
        }
      },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: './styles/style.css', disable: true, allChunks: true }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'vendors', to: 'vendors' }]),
    new OpenBrowserPlugin({ url: 'http://localhost:8080' }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

It seems as if it always uses "../bundle.js" to find it for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you,

Comment: check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34125010/3148807) helps

Comment: I tried the different suggestions, but still can't get it to work - I will try and see if I can find some other boilerplate with an example of exactly this and then backtrack from there... thanks anyway