# Routing not working in a webpack + react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm building an app with webpack + React + react-router + typescript and I got stuck with the routing, I have two routes, the default '/' and '/test', no matter what I do only the default is reach. I did a lot of research and find many people with the same problem, but all the solutions they gave did not work for me.

I tried:

- Add historyApiFallback: true in the webpack.config (https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-react-router).
- Add the public path: ouput: { ... publicPath: '/', }
- Tried to use proxy like in this example: [How to allow for webpack-dev-server to allow entry points from react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203725/how-to-allow-for-webpack-dev-server-to-allow-entry-points-from-react-router)

I guess because of my lack of knowledge with wepack I'm missing something, can someone help?

Here's my code:

Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: '3000',
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};
```

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';
import SurveyList from './pages/survey/list';

import messages from './intl/messages';
import { getStoredLanguage } from './intl/languageStorage';

function App() {
  const [appLang, setAppLang] = useState(getStoredLanguage());

  return (
    <IntlProvider
      locale={appLang}
      messages={appLang === 'en' ? messages.en : messages.pt}
    >
      <Router>
        <Link to='/'>Dashboard</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to='/test'>Surveys</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/test'>
            <SurveyList />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 16):

For anybody still having this issue, make sure to add this to your webpack config.

```js
output: {
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

Comment: I tried to fix it for hours and finally with this I was able to.

Comment: `historyApiFallback` it was what i was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the problem was not the webpack, but the lack of the attribute 'exact' in the main route otherwise all other routes are going to match with the main.

```
<Route exact path='/'>
```